# Indexes turn SQL query too slow

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'm having a huge issue on a SQL query, after I added an index.

```
declare @DateFromCT date, @DateToCT date;
declare @DateFromCT2 date, @DateToCT2 date;
set dateformat dmy;
set @DateFromCT= '1/1/2015'; set @DateToCT= '31/3/2015';
set @DateFromCT2= '1/4/2015'; set @DateToCT2= '30/4/2015';
Select distinct CT.CodCliente,ct.codacesso FROM CT_Contabilidade CT 
Inner join CD_PlanoContas PC ON CT.CodAcesso = PC.Cod
WHERE NOT exists (
    SELECT 1 FROM ct_contabilidade CT2
    WHERE CT2.CodAcesso = CT.CodAcesso 
    and CT2.Data between @DateFromCT2 and @DateToCT2
    And ( CT2.CodEmpresa = 1) And CT2.codcliente = ct.codcliente    )
and CT.Data between @DateFromCT and @DateToCT
AND PC.subgrupo = 'C' 
And ( CT.CodEmpresa = 1 )  And ct.codCliente > 0
```

The CT_Contabilidade's PK is a Sequential (bigint identity), clustered index.
It has 1.5 million records.

Without other non-clustered indexes, it performs well, took less than 1 second. That's OK for me.

I create an index over the CodAcesso to match `CD_PlanoContas key (cod);`
The CD_PlanoContas PK (clustered index) is Cod.

It's still performing well. No notable difference...

So I create a index over the codCliente (since it also refers another table)

... And after this, the query is TOO slow; it is taking 7 or 8 MINUTES.

- If I drop the CodAcesso index, it turn to be ok.
- If I drop the CodCliente index, it is ok too.
- If I let them both, but change the query , taking of the Inner Join with CD_Planocontas (and consequently , the filter "AND PC.subgrupo = 'C'")   it is OK.

I can't imagine the indexes are causing the query to behave that way.

It's a HUGE difference, not just a "loss of performance". I try some other things, as take out each filter... not changed.

The execution plan suggests an index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[CT_Contabilidade] ([CodEmpresa],[Data],[CodCliente])
INCLUDE ([CodAcesso])
```

I created it, and the query works fine, even with the 2 other indexes (codCliente and codAcesso)

But I didn't like to create a specific index to this query (it's just one of many queries that uses these tables).

If runs well without no index, I think it should runs at least EQUAL with this 2 indexes.

What causes the performance to change so drastically? What do I need to change to speed things up?

Answer (score 1):

try using an index optimizer hint to control which index is being used.

for example:

select * 
from titles with (index (titleind))
where title = 'The Gourmet Microwave'

use the 'set statistics io on' command to see the number of pages being scanned with each query/index combo and use the 'rightclick/show execution plan' option to see how the query is being executed

Comment: I tried hint to force query uses the pk (clustered index). It works fine. Even existing both indexes (codAcesso and codCliente), the query process ran fine (less than 1 second).
The problem is: I think the query optimizer should choose the right indexes. It's not what is happening, if exists both indexes (codCliente and CodAcesso), and I don't "hint" the query to use the PK (on the ct_contabilidade), it takes more than 7 MINUTES.
I just would like to UNDERSTAND what happen, to prevent future problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always good idea to follow the suggestion of execution plan.

I suggest you compare the execution plan before and after adding index and see the difference. Maybe that index cause SQL engine to choose a bad plan.

Also try update statistics on your table and index and see how if affects.

Comment: yeap,  SQL Server really choose a bad plan. I have to hint index the sub-query (after "EXISTS") to force the query use PK_CT_Contabilidade, and not the non-clustered indexes.